# Is the Suit/Django templates editable for the customization of the admin panel?

Tags: django-admin, django-cms

In our project we use suit CMS for the admin panel. But I want to know whether they can be overridden to add more features to different models in the application? If so, how ?

Answers in detail with reference will be appreciated.

Just for an information:

I have gone through the suit documentation. But didn't get whether those admin templates can be edited for my models to add more features.

Answer (score 0):

Anything in Django can be overridden, if you mimic its path in your project.

I've never come across Suit before, so don't know it's structure, but if you've got a template in site-packages that has a path like `templates/suit/admin/file.html` you simply need to mimic `suit/admin/file.html` in one of your template directories.